# How long would it take to beat Minecraft with 3 people?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Could me and two friends beat the entire game of Minecraft (killing the dragon) in a night?  How many hours would it take if that was our sole goal?

Comment: Not long: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxXrEmhTalI - Speedruns of 1 player in less than 20 minutes. However this is not something we can give an objective answer to.

Comment: Try it and let us know. That's the best way to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the generosity of the world seed for loot and nether fortresses, the enderman spawns and drops for pearls, if characters do not waste any time by dying or *building* during the run, a random seed dragon run can take between 30 minutes and 3-4 hours for 1 player with some experience in doing so. With 3 players, it could take a few minutes longer or shorter, depending on teamwork.

This isn't really the most fun way to play minecraft with friends, but it can be done in a night.